# Issue using tensorflow loadGraphModel from a signed URL on node.js

Tags: tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I have uploaded the model.json file of my tensorflow graph to a private repository on an AWS S3 bucket, and am now trying to load the graph with the `loadGraphModel` (alongside with the binary files of the weight manifest values, group1-shard1of1). Here's my code, which I run with node (I've kept the bucket path and signature keys private)

```
TFJSConverter = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-converter')
const MODEL_URL = "https://[BucketName].s3.amazonaws.com/[PathToModel]/model.json?[credentials]&[securitykey]";
global.fetch = require('node-fetch')
TFJSConverter.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL)
```

However the loadGraphModel function looks for a model url ending with '.json'. If not, it looks for the full model url and checks for a weight manifest file called weights_manifest.json, with no signature. An error request then follows:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request to https://[BucketName].s3.amazonaws.com/[PathToModel]/model.json?[credentials]&[securitykey],https://[BucketName].s3.amazonaws.com/[PathToModel]/weights_manifest.json failed with status code 403. Please verify this URL points to the model JSON of the model to load.

I've checked that the signed url actually works, is there a solution for signed urls?

Installed versions:
@tensorflow/tfjs-converter@1.1.2
node v10.15.3

Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe download it to a temp directory and load it from there?

Answer (score 2):

The correct library to use to load the model is `tfjs` and not `tfjs-converter`

```
let tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs");
tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL)
```

`403` error is an authorization error response. Try to set the credentials in the request using `requestInit` of the object passed as parameter of `loadGraphModel`

Comment: I've added header with the signature:
_const mycred = '[mySignature]'; 
var myHeader = {'Authorization':mycred}; 
var myInit = {headers: myHeader}; 
const model = tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL,{requestInit:myInit});_
and I now get this error: 
_Error: Request to https://s3.amazonaws.com/[PathToModel]/model.json failed with status code 400. Please verify this URL points to the model JSON of the model to load._

Comment: Can you check the network tab in the developer tool of chrome, to see if the headers are set for the ajax requests to retrieve the model files?

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work @tlc91? From my understanding, presigned S3 urls are limited to a single key (e.g. the `model.json` file), and `tf.loadGraphModel` would attempt to download the rest of the `bin` files in the defined prefix.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
global.fetch = fetch
```

but you can also try:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL, { fetchFunc: fetch } )
```

as described in the documentation:
https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#loadGraphModel